# How does the function in this array filter work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

I'm doing a beginner exercise, find the mean/median/mode/range of `var numbers = [23,9,14,2,28,19,3,15,9,25,2,4,9]`. Mean was simple, but I have to get the numbers unique for the median. I came across something that works perfectly for that:

```
var numbersUnique = numbers.filter(
    function(i, j, k) {
        return j === k.indexOf(i);
    }
)
```

It even sorts them. I don't know how it works though. I skimmed [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679973(v=vs.94).aspx)  but there's nothing similar really.

I wasn't even aware that you could return something with a comparative operator. I thought it might be shorthand for `if (j === k.indexOf(i)) { return j; }` but that logs `[3, 4, 9, 14, 15, 19, 23, 25, 28]` not `[2, 3, 4, 9, 14, 15, 19, 23, 25, 28]` like the original one.

What is the function doing exactly?

Complete code

```
var numbers = [23, 9, 14, 2, 28, 19, 3, 15, 9, 25, 2, 4, 9];

// Mean

var numbersTotal = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbersTotal += numbers[i];
}

var numbersMean = (numbersTotal / numbers.length);

console.log("The mean is " + numbersMean);

// Median

var numbersSorted = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
})

var numbersUnique = numbers.filter(function (i, j, k) {
    return j === k.indexOf(i);
})

console.log(numbersUnique);
```

Comment: Why did I get `[23, 9, 14, 2, 28, 19, 3, 15, 25, 4]` rather than your sorted result when I tried in Chrome console. And my result makes sense to you I think.

Comment: @JasmineOT Oh strange. Somehow the sort method carries over even though I assigned it to a variable. I'm brand new to this so forgive me. Edited my post with complete code.

Comment: That's much clear. You did the sorting yourself. And after you use `sort( )` to an array, the array will keep the new sorted array.

Comment: maybe change your callback variables to some more meaningful, than `i, j, k`.

Comment: @JasmineOT okay gotcha, I only noticed there were duplicates after sorting so that's how that happened

Comment: Simply, `sort()` sorts your array and `filter()` removes the duplicated element for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` function only keeps the elements for which the function returns `true` or truthy value.

In your case,

```
return j === k.indexOf(i);
```

Here,

- `i` is the current element in the loop.
- `j` is the current index in the loop
- `k` is the input array

And `k.indexOf(i)` will return the first index of the element in the array. If the index of the current element in the loop, i.e. `j` is same as the first index in the array, it'll return `true` and `false` otherwise.

So, basically it return `true` for the *first* value in the array and if the array contain a value more than once(*duplicate values*) it returns `false` and the element is not included in the filtered array.

---

Giving meaningful names to the variables will make you easy to understand the code by just looking at it

```
var numbersUnique = numbers.filter(
    function (element, index, array) {
    //        ^^^^^^^                    The current element in the array
    //                 ^^^^^             The index of the current element in array
    //                        ^^^^^      Original Array

    return index === array.indexOf(element);
});
```

Note: When I used `current` in the above explanation it means the respective entity when looping.

Comment: Gave you the answer cause this is more specific/answers my question. But what is the reason for using a parameter for the input array at all? Since it's a method for the array in the first place

Comment: @delz The context inside the filter function is not the array on which it is called it's `window`

Comment: Your edit is helpful but I don't fully understand how it filters. Why is `return 1 === numbers.indexOf(9)` (the first 9) true but not `return 12 === numbers.indexOf(9)` (the last 9)? Does it just force each element to be unique by its nature, ie. 12 can't be the index of 9 because we already know 1 is?

Comment: @delz Because `indexOf` always returns the first index on which the passed element is found

Answer (score -1):

Filter function must return 'true' or 'false'. First of all read attentively this [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

and then you can explain to yourself how your filter function works

Comment: That explains it so much better. I went to the Microsoft one because I thought that one was specific to prototypes. Thanks!